# Sending mail with tracking number in Kentico

Tags: c#, kentico

I am working on E-commerce portal using Kentico 9, i just need to send mail to the customer on updating shipping tracking number.

can anyone tell me if it is available or not to add such behavior to Kentico and if so tell me how or where to search as i am new to Kentico.

Comment: [Configuring basic settings of notification emails](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Configuring+e-commerce+email+notifications#Configuringe-commerceemailnotifications-Configuringbasicsettingsofnotificationemails)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into the Order Status feature of the e-commerce?  If you added a status for Tracking Number confirmed or something like that you can choose to send a notification.

You would then create an e-mail template which would contain the number from the shipping provider.  Depending on how your system is setup, you might need to add an additional custom field to your orders to store the tracking number and then pull that in via the template macros dynamically

Answer (score 1):

I can give you almost what you are asking for. It doesn't react to a change in tracking #; instead, it reacts to a change in order status.  Since your question title implies that you want the tracking number to appear in the email, I've included that, too.  Hopefully I haven't missed any configuration settings...

**Configuration**

In `Store Configuration -> Order Status`, edit the 'Shipped' status and enable `Send notification`.

In `Email templates`, edit 'E-commerce - Order status notification to customer'.
(You may need to switch to global view to see it.)
Somewhere in the body of the template, add something like `Tracking number: {% Order.OrderTrackingNumber %}`

**User instructions**

In `Orders`, edit an order whose status is not `Shipped`.  In `Shipping`, enter a tracking number and click `Save`.  In `General`, change the `Status` to `Shipped` and click `Save`.
The email address under `Customer` should soon receive the status update email with the tracking number.